# MFC Dialogue based application

Tags: mfc, bitblt, dialogbasedapp

Good day, I am trying to add a bitmap image to my dialogue-based application using MFC ( VSTUDIO 2019 ). I wish to position my image at the center of the application. How do I get the size of the current rectangle so that it can be given as an input to `BitBlt()` function? Thanks in advance

Comment: `GetClientRect` should do it for the dialog window as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use [`GetClientRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclientrect) to get the dimensions use refer to. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70826096/2287576) provides some additonal information about `GetClientRect` and the other variants.

Comment: Dear andrew truckle, it worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please upvote and accept. 